# Combo Box is not updating through SQL Data Adapter

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, dataadapter

I am having a strange problem and I have no clue whether it is happening due to bad connection or something else is causing this.
The problem I have a combo box and I am populating the values using SQL Data Table in "Form Load" event and it was working fine until today. Every time the form loaded both the combo boxes are empty one for date and other for company name. The code I am using is below.

```
public DataTable getResult(string query)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
private void Reports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RevenueDate_dt = func.getResult(dateQuery);

        foreach (DataRow dr in RevenueDate_dt.Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["Global_Period_Month"].ToString());
        }

        Gpn_dt = func.getResult(GpnQuery);

        foreach (DataRow dr in Gpn_dt.Rows)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(dr["gpnname"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

The query showing perfect result when I am executing it on SQL Server.
Looking forward for answers.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in "return dt".  What does the datatable look like.

Comment: It is showing rows 80 and no table name! And still the combo box is empty.The query is fine and connection is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what's happening, but I wonder if the datatable isn't a little overkill for what you want.  It seems a normal DataReader would have a lot less overhead and would be easier to debug.  Something like this:

```
public string[] getResult(string query, string ColumnName)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int col = reader.GetOrdinal(ColumnName);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        results.Add(reader.GetString(col));
    }

    reader.Close();

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

And then to add the items to your combo boxes, it would simply look like this:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(func.getResult(dateQuery, "Global_Period_Month"));
comboBox2.Items.AddRange(func.getResult(GpnQuery, "gpnname"));
```

Comment: Thank you @Hambone and yes it is a very typical situation also for me that day before yesterday the code works fine but then it crashes but anyway thanks for the answer and code works for me now. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Datatables are a double-edged sword.  Very useful and handle a lot of the heavy lifting, but they have some rough edges.  I'm glad this worked for you.